# Why am I getting SAS error when running the enclosed proc sql code

Tags: sql, sas

I cannot understand why I am getting the following errors when running the code below:

27         WHERE (FC_ATTORNEY_ID, REC_CHNG_DT) IN
                                _
                                79
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a (.

35         ) AND REC_CHNG_CD In ('A','C')
36         ;
           _
           79
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).

```
proc sql;

create table test as
SELECT DISTINCT 
FC_ATTORNEY_ID, FC_ATTORNEY_NM, REC_CHNG_DT
FROM RDX_BDE.T_FORECLOSURE T_FORECLOSURE
WHERE (FC_ATTORNEY_ID, REC_CHNG_DT) IN
(
SELECT
FC_ATTORNEY_ID
, MAX (REC_CHNG_DT) AS LST_DT
FROM RDX_BDE.T_FORECLOSURE T_FORECLOSURE
WHERE  REC_CHNG_CD In ('A','C')
GROUP BY FC_ATTORNEY_ID
) AND REC_CHNG_CD In ('A','C')
;quit;
```

trying to avoid the two errors I described.  I received this code from another programmer however they are using TOAD, not SAS

Comment: do format your code

Answer (score 0):

You have `T_FORCLOSURE` twice in your `FROM` and `WHERE` statements.

One with the table identifier and one without.

Remove the redundant code to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this syntax:

```
(FC_ATTORNEY_ID, REC_CHNG_DT) IN ....
```

You cannot use the IN operator in that way.  You can only use it with a single value not some type of composite object.

Valid syntax is like your other usage:

```
REC_CHNG_CD IN ('A','C')
```

or

```
REC_CHNG_CD IN (select code_var from ....)
```

If you do need to test if tuple of values exist then recode your query to use EXISTS instead.

But it looks like you are just asking for the MAX date.

```
create table test as
  SELECT FC_ATTORNEY_ID, FC_ATTORNEY_NM, max(REC_CHNG_DT) as REC_CHNG_DT
  FROM RDX_BDE.T_FORECLOSURE T_FORECLOSURE
  WHERE  REC_CHNG_CD In ('A','C')
  GROUP BY FC_ATTORNEY_ID, FC_ATTORNEY_NM
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting, for each attorney, the rows with the newest recorded change date.

One simpler way is to use the HAVING clause on an automatically remerged group aggregate

```
proc sql;
  create table test as
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    FC_ATTORNEY_ID, FC_ATTORNEY_NM, REC_CHNG_DT
  FROM
    RDX_BDE.T_FORECLOSURE
  WHERE
    REC_CHNG_CD IN ('A','C')
  GROUP BY
    FC_ATTORNEY_ID
  HAVING 
    REC_CHNG_DT = MAX (REC_CHNG_DT)
  ;
```